# Recursive Find and Replacing String?

Tags: java, string, recursion, replace, find

My question is about finding and replacing strings in a text file.
This program is supposed to find the instances of the word `ghost` within `A Christmas Carol` text file and replace them with `bunny` for `ghost`, `Bunny` for `Ghost` and `BUNNY` for `GHOST`. It works for lowercase ghost, and there are no instances of `GHOST`, but it doesn't seem to work for just capitalized `Ghost`.
I know my issue is within the last two methods. What am I doing wrong?

```
    package findandreplace;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class FindAndReplace {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "24022-0.txt"; //Charles Dickens - A Christmas Carol
        try {
            Scanner fin = getScannerFromFile(filename);
            String [] story = readFile(fin);
            String [] newStory = new String[story.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < story.length; i++) {
                newStory[i] = substitute(story[i], "ghost", "bunny");
            }

            if (writeFile("bunny.txt", newStory))
                System.out.println("New file successfully created.");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static Scanner getScannerFromFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File f = new File(filename);
        return new Scanner(f);
    }



    private static String [] readFile(Scanner fin) {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        while (fin.hasNext()) {
            lines.add(fin.nextLine());
        }
        return lines.toArray(new String[0]);
    }


    private static boolean writeFile(String newfile, String [] lines) {
        File file = new File(newfile);
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File already exists");
        }
        try {
            PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(file);
            for (String line : lines) {
                fout.println(line);
            }
            fout.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("File error.");
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * This method should examine the first word, and return the second word matching case.
     * For example, if first word is "GHOST", and second word is "bunny", the return value
     * should be "BUNNY".
     * NOTE: THIS SHOULD *NOT* BE A RECURSIVE FUNCTION
     * precondition: the first word is all lowercase, Capitalized, or ALL-CAPS
     * @return second, matching case of first
     */
    private static String matchWordCase(String first, String second) {
         if (first.toUpperCase().equals(first)) {
         second = second.toUpperCase();
        }
        if (first.toLowerCase().equals(first)) {
            second = second.toLowerCase();
        }
        else if (first.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == first.charAt(0)) {
            second = second.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + second.substring(1);
        }
        return second;
    } 

    /**
     * This method should return line, with every instance of the word find
     * should be replaced by replace. There are multiple approaches you can take,
     * but words should match regardless of case, and case should be preserved.
     * If you want to assume words are space-separated, you may. However, it is
     * better if you figure out how to do this otherwise.
     * NOTE: THIS SHOULD BE A RECURSIVE FUNCTION
     * @return line - with the appropriate substitutions
     */
    private static String substitute(String line, String find, String replace) {
        StringBuilder newLine = new StringBuilder();
        //TODO:
        String result;
        if (line.length() < find.length()) {
            return line;
        }

        if (find.equals(line.substring(0,find.length()))) {
         line = matchWordCase(find, replace) + 
         substitute(line.substring(find.length()), find, matchWordCase(find, 
         replace));
        } else {
            result = line.charAt(0) + substitute(line.substring(1), find, 
        replace);
        }


        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to call my matchWordCase method in my substitute method in every way I can think of. This is what I have now and it still isn't matching the word case.

Answer (score 0):

In your `substitute` method's `if` statement, should the condition be `find.equalsIgnoreCase`, instead of `find.equals`?

Comment: Doing that just outputted all instances of "ghost" and "Ghost" to "bunny" when it should output "bunny" for "ghost" and "Bunny" for "Ghost". Worth the try though, thanks.

Comment: I think I may have confused you with the wording of my question. I edited it at the top.

Comment: Well, you have a method `matchWordCase` that (I assume) is meant to do exactly what the method says, that you've not called anywhere in your code.

Comment: What you'll most likely need to do is call `matchWordCase` somewhere in your recursive `substitute` function, passing in the appropriate strings as arguments so that their cases are matched.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: No worries mate. Best of luck with the exercise! Feel free to accept this answer if it's helped.